# Replace the first header text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have headers like

```
<h3 class="left_header">First job partner</h3>
<h3 class="left_header" style="text-align:center;">Don't have an account ?</h3>
```

Now i want to replace the first header with Job partner. how to do it by jQuery or Java script.

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: I have tried like this..`jQuery(".left_header h3").html("Public offers");` but it didn't worked. I need to change first one only

Comment: `.left_header h3` means "select all h3 having parent with class left_header". What you need is "select first h3 having class left_header" which translates to `h3.left_header:first`. HTH

Comment: jQuery("h3.left_header:first") not jQuery(".left_header h3")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to grab the `h3` tags with the class `.left_header` and take the first instance from the element collection using `:first` selector,

```
$('h3.left_header:first').text('Job partner')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9K5/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('h3:first-child').html('sublink_active');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3y9K5/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("h3:first-child").html("Job Partner")
```

### demo

Answer (score 2):

try with this.

```
$(".left_header:first").html("yourNewTitle");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use`.first()` (http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$( "h3" ).first().html("Job partner");
```

OR

you can use `jQuery( ":first" )` (https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$(".left_header:first").html("Job partner");
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nagarkoti/3y9K5/6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

JQuery :

`$('.left_header').first().text("Job Partner");`

Answer (score 1):

Your code :

```
jQuery(".left_header h3").text("Public offers");
```

your code didn't match with your requirement. Because above code select all h3 elements under the "left_header" class. And In your HTML `h3` have an class `left_header`. So you should use following selector to select elements-

```
$("h3.left_header");
```

Now you want to select only first element, so you can use index number like this -

```
document.getElementsByClassName("left_header")[0].innerText = "Job Partner";
```

OR

```
var g = $("h3.left_header");
$(g[0]).text("Job Partner");
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk3gw/9/)

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk3gw/10/)

Note: There are more than one way exist to accomplish this task-

```
$(".left_header:first").text("Job Partner");
```

[Working demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk3gw/11/)

Comment: A simple suggestion dont use html it will effect other headers so use text. For me .text() worked instead of .html()

Comment: @RIADev: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right ".html()" effect all the child elements. Please see updated answer. :)